# Arithmetic Operation with JPA on a DB Field of Type String

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

Is there any proper way to use arithmetic methods (sum, avg, etc.) of CriteriaBuilder class with a String property (VARCHAR column) of an Entity class?

Here is related field:

```
@Column(name="GRADE")
private String grade;
```

And what I want to do is:

```
Expression ex = criteriaBuilder.avg(root.get("grade");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use **Aggregate Functions** on String (VARCHAR) datatype.

In the reffrence of Oracle http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/doc.1111/e12048/funcbltag.htm

Normal Usesage of Aggregate Function in Hibernate is by Using hibernate `projections`

```
List results = session.createCriteria(SomeClass.class)
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()        
        .add( Projections.avg("someCloumn") )       
    )
    .list();
```

This is also for only for column witch is having **datatype** as **bitint, float and int** only.